# Search NSArray for value matching value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsarray

I have an NSArray of `objects`, which has a particular property called `name` (type NSString).
I have a second NSArray of NSStrings which are `names`.

I'd like to get an NSArray of all the `objects` whose `.name` property matches one of the `names` in the second NSArray.

How do I go about this, fast and efficiently as this will be required quite often.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With your current data structures, you can only do it in O(n^2) time by looping over the first array once for each member of the second array:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString * name in names) {
    for (MyObject * object in objects) {
        if ([[myObject name] isEqualToString:name]) {
            [array addObject:object];
        }
    }
}
```

(Alternate as suggested by Stefan: loop over the objects array and ask the names array if it `containsObject:` for the name of each object.)

But if this really needs to be faster (really depends on the size of the arrays as much as how often you do it), you can improve this by introducing an NSDictionary that maps the `names` in the first array to their objects. Then each of those lookups is O(1) and the overall time is O(n). (You'd have to keep this dictionary always in sync with the array of objects, which isn't hard with reasonable accessors. This technique also has the constraint that the same `name` can't appear on more than one object.)

An alternate way of getting this result (and which doesn't have that last constraint) is to use an NSSet for your second collection, then walk through the objects array calling `containsObject:` with each one on the set of names. Whether this technique is better depends on whether your two collections are roughly the same size, or if one is much larger than the other.

Comment: Why not use [names containsObject:object.name]?

Comment: @Stefan H: Sure, if that way of thinking about it works better with your head. Still n^2 though. :) (Edited)

Comment: Note that using an `NSDictionary` for the first array will only work if none of your objects contain the same `name` - depends on your domain.

That minor caveat aside, quixoto is correct - you won't improve this without redesigning your data structures.

Answer (score 75):

Why not just to use predicates to do that for you?:

```
// For number kind of values:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// For string kind of values:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// For any object kind of value (yes, you can search objects also):
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", value];
NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Why are string searches different than objects? Aren't NSStrings objects too?

Comment: Yes, they are and I am pretty sure you can. MATCHES is just dedicated for strings and you can add case options to it [cd].

Comment: +1 for this. Predicates also have now `predicateWithBlock` which is even more convenient.

Comment: The predicate format for "any object kind of value" is not correct.  `MATCHES` is only applicable to `NSString`s.  For a generic object, you should use the `==` operator to compare.  I.e.:
        `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", value];`
        `NSArray *results = [array_to_search filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`

Comment: @MarcJohnson While the effort to improve content is appreciated, the OP above explicitly states their data is of the type `NSString`, so a solution which only works for NSString is fine and doesn't need to be changed. KevinH's comment is useful information, but it's not necessary/ideal to replace the answerer's code above, which works just fine here. There are competing answers that use `==` if you want to upvote them, instead.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", nameToFind];
[listOfItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: But that will only find the object(s) with a single name, Their are multiple names that need to be found. (eg I want all the objects whose names are "Joe", "Bill", etc)

Comment: so change the predicate to [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", arrayOfNames], use KVC to grab the array of names you need like: [_arrayOfObjects valueForKeyPath:@"name"], which will give you an NSArray (or set in some instances) which you can use as your IN %@ argument for the predicate.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use this method:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [_items indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   return ((MyObject *)obj).name isEqualToString:name];
}];

if (indexes.count != 0) {
//extract your objects from the indexSet, and do what you like...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray * foundNames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (MyObject * objectWithName in objectCollection) {
    if ([names containsObject:objectWithName.name]) {
        [foundNames objectWithName];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The methods most helpful will be:

```
filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
```

and

```
indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
```

The second one uses a code block, not available on iOS before 4.0

Both of these will be more efficient than iterating directly.

There's a good example here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* solutions = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Object* object in objects){
   for (NSString* name in names){
       if ([object.name isEqualToString:name]){
          [solutions addObject:object];
          break; // If this doesnt work remove this
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not use [names containsObject:object.name]?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;

if (range.location!=NSNotFound)
  {                   
  [searchindex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]];           
  }
```